# Where can I find the exploded war file in Weblogic 12c?

Tags: jar, ejb, weblogic

I saw an upload folder inside the AdminServer - but it seems that it doesn't recognize or re-deploy the new sets of JARs files even after recycling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload folder is where weblogic stores uploaded files (with an ant deploy task or uploaded with the console). But it also references them in the `domain/config/config.xml` file. That's why it does not automatically deploy them (weblogic does not scan this folder).

What you want to use is the `domain/autodeploy` folder (which is only scanned by weblogic in development mode).

Comment: Thanks for the rsponse.